# Show that $(1+u) \log (1+u) - u \ge \frac{u^2}{2(1+u/3)} $

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis

This is used to go from Bennett's inequality to Bernstein's inequality.
Yet I don't understand how to prove the inequality.

Assume that $u > 0$, define
$$
h(u) = (1+u) \log (1+u) - u
$$
show that
$$
h(u) \ge \frac{u^2}{2(1+u/3)}
$$

---

My research :

Decomposing the function $h$ as a power series show that it is equivalent to
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{u^n}{n+1} \frac{n-1}{n (n+2)} \ge 0
$$
Sadly, I see no reason for this series to be positive.

---

**SOLUTION**

The twice differenciation technique given below works. However, I don't agree with the calculus, only on small things that don't change the result. Define
$$
g(u) = (1+u)\log (1+u) - u - \frac{3u^2}{2(3+u)}
$$
$$
g'(u) = \log (1+u) + 1 - 1 - \frac{3}{2} \frac{2u (3+u) - u^2}{(3+u)^2}\\
$$
Simplifying,
$$
g'(u) = \log (1+u) - \frac{3}{2} \frac{u(u+6 )}{(3+u)^2}  
$$
$$
g''(u) = \frac{1}{1+u} - \frac{3}{2} \frac{(2u +6)(3+u)^2 - 
2 (u+3)(u^2 + 6u) }{(3+u)^4}  
$$
Simplifying,

$$
g''(u) = \frac{1}{1+u} - \frac{3}{2} \frac{2u^2 +6u + 6u + 18 - 
2u^2 - 12u }{(3+u)^3}   =
 \frac{1}{1+u} - \frac{ 27  }{(3+u)^3} 
$$

Simplifying again,

$$
g''(u)= \frac{ u^3 + 3\times 3u^2 + 3 \times 9u + 27 - 27(1+u)}{(1+u)(3+u)^3} 
= \frac{ u^2(u+9)}{(1+u)(3+u)^3} > 0
$$
And the result is given by the reasoning of Clement.

Comment: From Bennett's to what? And have you tried to study the function $u\mapsto 2(1+u/3)h(u)/u^2$ via tedious differentiation?

Comment: From Bennett's inequality to *Bernstein's inequality (corrected).
Thank you for your answer, it seems that I didn't push it all the way through.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Typically, the brute-force, not-so-clever, usually conclusive method to prove $f\geq g$ is to study either $\frac{f}{g}$ or $f-g$ on the desired domain, and prove (by differentiation, invoking monotonicity, and evaluation at specific points) that either the ratio is at least 1, or the difference at least 0. In this case, the difference seems nicer, as we want to  "get rid of the logarithm" by differentiation as quickly as we can, and that's not going to happen by differentiating the ratio.*

Let $g$ be defined by $g(u) = h(u)-\frac{u^2}{2(1+\frac{u}{3})}$ for $u>0$.

$g$ is then smooth on its domain, and we have
$$\begin{align}
g'(u) &= \ln(1+u) - \frac{3u(u+6)}{2(u+3)^2}\\
g''(u) &=  \frac{u^2(u+9)}{(u+1)(u+3)^3} >0
\end{align}$$
for $u>0$. In particular, $g'$ is increasing, and since $\lim_{u\to 0^+} g'(u) = 0$, we know that $g'>0$.

*So $g$ is increasing.* But as $\lim_{u\to 0^+} g(u) = 0$ as well, this means $g>0$ on its domain; hence
$$
h(u) > \frac{u^2}{2(1+\frac{u}{3})} \qquad \forall u>0.
$$

Comment: It would've been faster to study $g(u)=\frac{h(u)}{1+u}-\frac{u^2}{2(1+\frac{u}{3})(1+u)}$, this way, you wouldn't have to differentiate it twice, otherwise, it's a good answer ^^

Comment: @OussamaBoussif I didn't really aim at efficiency too much, as long as I differentiate less than 3 times I'm happy. But indeed! (and now, I'm waiting for a one-line answer cleverly relying on convexity or magical insight).

Comment: @OussamaBoussif (Isn't there a factor $(1+u)$ missing in your second denominator?)

Comment: Yep, I'll fix it now ^^, it's still an ugly function to differentiate though

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't try that classic approach.
I agree with the reasoning but not with some constants in the calculus  that don't change the result.
I added my calculations to the answer. Hope you'll agree.

Comment: @RobinVogel You are right, I was missing a $2$ in the first derivative, and had an extra $3u$ in the second. Thanks for spotting it, I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Your inequality is related to the Padé approximation $$\frac{(x-1)(x+5)}{4x+2}$$ of $\log(x)$. In fact one can show (e.g. see below) that $$\log(x) \leq \frac{(x-1)(x+5)}{4x+2}$$ for all $x>0$. (This is a useful inequality to remember.) Substituting $x\leftarrow 1/x$ reverses the inequality: $$\log(x)= -\log\left(\frac1x\right) \geq -\frac{(\frac1x-1)(\frac1x+5)}{\frac4x+2} = \frac{(x-1)(5x + 1)}{x(2x+4)}.$$ As a direct consequence $$ x \log(x) - (x-1) \geq \frac{3(x-1)^2}{6+2(x-1)}.$$

Here is one way to prove the inequality for the Padé approximation. Fix  $x \geq 1$ and let $f(t) = (t-1)^2(x-t)$. Then $f(1)=f(x)=0$ and $f(t) \geq 0$ for $t \in[1, x]$. Integration by parts shows $$\int_1^x \frac{f'(t)}t \mathrm{d}t = \int_1^x \frac{f(t)}{t^2}\mathrm{d}t \geq 0.$$ Now the integral on the left can be easily computed: $$\int_1^x \frac{f'(t)}t \mathrm{d}t = (x-1)(x+5)/2-(2x+1)\log(x).$$ A similar argument works for $0<x\leq 1$ (now $f(t)\leq 0$ on the interval $[x,1]$).

Comment: Could you explain the inequality behind "as a direct consequence"? It appears not trivial to me, and I didn't get that why people find $\frac{3(x-1)^2}{6+2(x-1)}$ as lower bound at the first place..

Comment: @M.K Remember that $x>0$. Now multiply the inequality just above it by $x$ and subtract $x-1$ on both sides.